# Indy Mail server

Tags: delphi

Following is my code for the smtp client for sending email

```
    VAR SMTP : TIdSMTP;
 MSG : TIdmessage;
 begin


  MSG:=TIdmessage.Create(NIL);
  TRY
    WITH MSG.Recipients.Add DO BEGIN
      Name:='me025';
      Address:='me025@gmail.com'
    END;
    MSG.BccList.Add.Address:='me025@yahoo.com';
    MSG.From.Name:='self025';
    MSG.From.Address:='self025@127.0.1.1';
    MSG.Body.Text:='<Message Body>';
    MSG.Subject:='<Subject of message>';
    SMTP:=TIdSMTP.Create(NIL);
    TRY
      SMTP.Host:='127.0.1.1'; // IP Address of SMTP server
      // 127.0.1.1
      SMTP.Port:=25; // Port address of SMTP service (usually 25)
      SMTP.Connect;
      TRY
        SMTP.Send(MSG)
      FINALLY
        SMTP.Disconnect
      END
    FINALLY
      SMTP.Free
    END
  FINALLY
    MSG.Free
  END;

 end;
```

which will use a SMTPserver in same pc

the smtp server is a working indy 10 unofficial sample
http://indy.fulgan.com/ZIP/Indy10demo.zip

whenever i connect to the server "Socket error # 11001 Host not found " error occers

but smtp server is receiving all the parameters correctly and showing correctly on the GUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has your PC an address of 127.0.1.1 or are you trying to use localhost (127.0.0.1)? People should get used to DNS names... as soon as IPv6 will become mainstream at least people won't be able any longer to remember IP numbers easily :)

Comment: thanks now very thing works well (server gets the parameters) and no any exceptions are raised, but the receiver can't get the mail

Comment: @vibeeshanRC: `TIdSMTPServer` only accepts the raw email data from an SMTP client, like `TIdSMTP`, nothing else.  It is your responsibility in your code to then deliver that email data to the intended recipient(s) yourself, either by storing the data in a local storage for later access by a POP3 and/or IMAP4 client, or to forward the email to another SMTP server. If that delivery is not working, then you are not storing/forwarding the data correctly, so please show the code that stored and retreives the data.

Comment: @RemyLebeau do you know of any good tutorials for both mail client & SMTP server using Indy?