# Using INDY SMTPServer

Tags: delphi, indy

following code is what i modified(to work with 10.5.8) form the sample in order to send email independently using the smtp client described in  [Indy Mail server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489820/indy-mail-server)

following is from INDY smtpserver sample

```
procedure TForm1.btnServerOnClick(Sender: TObject);
 begin

 IdSMTPServer1.active := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnServerOffClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

 IdSMTPServer1.active := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdSMTPServer1MailFrom(ASender: TIdSMTPServerContext;
  const AAddress: string; AParams: TStrings; var VAction: TIdMailFromReply);
begin
// Here we are testing the MAIL FROM line sent to the server.
 // MAIL FROM address comes in via AAddress. VAction sets the return action to the server.

 // The following actions can be returned to the server:
 { mAccept, mReject }

 // For now, we will just always allow the mail from address.
 VAction := mAccept;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdSMTPServer1MsgReceive(ASender: TIdSMTPServerContext;
  AMsg: TStream; var LAction: TIdDataReply);
var
 LMsg : TIdMessage;
 LStream : TFileStream;
begin
// When a message is received by the server, this event fires.
// The message data is made available in the AMsg : TStream.
// In this example, we will save it to a temporary file, and the load it using
// IdMessage and parse some header elements.

LStream := TFileStream.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.exename) + 'test.eml', fmCreate);
Try
 LStream.CopyFrom(AMsg, 0);
Finally
 FreeAndNil(LStream);
End;

LMsg := TIdMessage.Create;
Try
 LMsg.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.exename) + 'test.eml', False);
 ToLabel.Caption := LMsg.Recipients.EMailAddresses;
 FromLabel.Caption := LMsg.From.Text;
 SubjectLabel.Caption := LMsg.Subject;
 Memo1.Lines := LMsg.Body;
Finally
 FreeAndNil(LMsg);
End;

end;


procedure TForm1.IdSMTPServer1UserLogin(ASender: TIdSMTPServerContext;
  const AUsername, APassword: String; var VAuthenticated: Boolean);
begin
 // This event is fired if a user attempts to login to the server
 // Normally used to grant relay access to specific users etc.
 VAuthenticated := True;
end;



procedure TForm1.IdSMTPServer1RcptTo(ASender: TIdSMTPServerContext;
  const AAddress: string; AParams: TStrings; var VAction: TIdRCPToReply;
  var VForward: string);
begin
   VAction := rAddressOk;    
end;

procedure TForm1.IdSMTPServer1Received(ASender: TIdSMTPServerContext;
  var AReceived: string);
begin
//
end;
```

what do i have to add to this project to work as email sending server.

I haven't done many changes to the original sample(only for compatibility) as i can't understand most of the concepts behind how email is sent and received. please explain me how to make this code to send email to the destination(eg: someone@gmail.com) given in this question  [Indy Mail server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489820/indy-mail-server) (smtpclient),

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking for exactly. Please clearify your question.

Comment: thanks i have updated please see the last paragraph ; you said  "If that delivery is not working, then you are not storing/forwarding the data correctly, so please show the code that stored and retreives the data" in the privious post , That is it

Comment: previous post = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489820/indy-mail-server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pass the email on to another system (Gmail in this case), use the `TIdSMTPRelay` component, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.IdSMTPServer1RcptTo(ASender: TIdSMTPServerContext;                
  const AAddress: string; AParams: TStrings; var VAction: TIdRCPToReply;                
  var VForward: string);                
begin                
  if (AAddress represents a user in your network) then
    VAction := rAddressOk
  else if (AAddress is outside of your network) then
    VAction := rWillForward;                    
end;

procedure TForm1.IdSMTPServer1MsgReceive(ASender: TIdSMTPServerContext; AMsg: TStream; var LAction: TIdDataReply); 
var 
  LMsg : TIdMessage; 
  LMsgClient: TIdMessageClient;
  LStream : TFileStream; 
  LRelayRecipients: TIdEMailAddressList;
  LRelay: TIdSMTPRelay;
  I: Integer;
begin 
  // When a message is received by the server, this event fires. 
  // The message data is made available in the AMsg : TStream. 
  // In this example, we will save it to a temporary file, and load it using 
  // IdMessage to parse some header elements. 

  LStream := TFileStream.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.exename) + 'test.eml', fmCreate); 
  Try 
    LStream.CopyFrom(AMsg, 0); 
  Finally 
    LStream.Free; 
  End; 
  AMsg.Position := 0;

  LMsg := TIdMessage.Create; 
  Try 
    //LMsg.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.exename) + 'test.eml', False); 

    // Do not use the TIdMessage.LoadFrom...() methods here! The email
    // data contained in the AMsg stream does not escape leading periods
    // on lines of text. That escaping is only used when the email was
    // transmitted over the socket, as a period character has special
    // meaning to the SMTP protocol.  TIdSMTPServer removes the escaping
    // from the data before firing this event. However, the LoadFrom...()
    // methods (which uses TIdMessageClient internally) require the
    // data to be escaped!  This is a known limitation in Indy's core
    // architecture and will be addressed in Indy 11.  Until then,
    // use TIdMessageClient manually so the necessary escaping can be
    // re-introduced into the data while it is being parsed...

    LMsgClient := TIdMessageClient.Create(nil);
    try
      LMsgClient.IOHandler := TIdIOHandlerStreamMsg.Create(LMsgClient, AMsg);
      with TIdIOHandlerStreamMsg(LMsgClient.IOHandler) do
      begin
        FreeStreams := False;
        EscapeLines := True;
      end;
      LMsgClient.IOHandler.Open;
      LMsgClient.ProcessMessage(LMsg, False);
    finally
      LMsgClient.Free;
    end;

    // process LMsg as needed...

    // save the email for local users and forward it to other SMTP servers as needed...

    LRelayRecipients := nil;
    try
      for I := 0 to ASender.RCPTList.Count-1 do
      begin
        if (ASender.RCPTList[I] represents a user in your network) then
        begin
          // save AMsg in the user's mailbox somewhere on the local
          // machine/network where an POP3/IMAP4 client can retreive
          // it from later...
        end else
        begin
          if not Assigned(LRelayRecipients) then LRelayRecipients := TIdEMailAddressList.Create(nil);
          LRelayRecipients.Add.Assign(ASender.RCPTList[I]);
        end;
      end;

      if Assigned(LRelayRecipients) then
      begin
        LRelay := TIdSMTPRelay.Create(nil);
        try
          // you must supply the IP/Host of a DNS server that
          // will be used for determining the SMTP server of
          // each recipient domain...
          LRelay.DNSServer := ...;

          LRelay.Send(LMsg, LRelayRecipients);
        finally
          LRelay.Free;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      LRelayRecipients.Free;
    end;

  Finally 
    LMsg.Free; 
  End; 
end;
```

Comment: @waza123: what about it? You didn't make any changes to it yet.  What you originally showed is incomplete.  My example above fills in some missing gaps for you, now you have to do the rest based on your particular business needs.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5854/discussion-between-waza123-and-remy-lebeau-teamb