# TIdSTMPServer OnMsgReceive event to redirect mail to other smtp servers

Tags: delphi, email, openssl, smtp, indy

I'm using `indy` and I'm hosting a mail server. I'd like to make a secure connection to other mail (`smtp`) servers without username/password from my `IdSMTPServer` so that if my server receives an email that's got to go to `yahoo` or `gmail` for example I can redirect it successfully. I tried Remy's answer to this topic [Using INDY SMTPServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499524/using-indy-smtpserver]) - using `IdSMTPRelay` but it didn't work for me. I also tried using `TIdSMTP` to send the message but if I leave the username/password fields unassigned I receive the error `Authentication required` from the smtp servers i'm sending the mail to. The `IdSMTPServer` has self signed OpenSSL certificates assigned to it with the `IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL` component so I suppose I should be able to achieve SSL connection but I just don't know how.

Comment: "using IdSMTPRelay ... didn't work for me" - what error or problem did you encounter? (Do you have some code example?)

Comment: @mjn When I got to the ``LRelay.Send(LMsg, LRelayRecipients);`` the execution stops for a few seconds and then continues without raising an exception - so the email is expected to be successfully sent but it never got to ``gmail``, ``yahoo`` or other mail servers.

Comment: Have you tried the debugger to see where in `Send` this execution stop happens?

Comment: @mjn The server where I test the application still doesn't have a ``Delphi IDE`` so I'm unable to debug there.

Comment: Have you considering using the *Remote* debugger? You don't need the IDE itself to be installed on the server. Also, have you tried attaching a `TIdLog...` component to `TIdSMTPRelay` to see what commands it is sending to Gmail/Yahoo?

Comment: If I attach a ``TIdLogFile`` to the ``TIdSMTPRelay.Intercept`` property all I see in my log file is "``Stat disconnected.``" and I guess I'll have to try this _Remote_ debugger out.