# Can I attach my server SSL certificates to the TIdSMTPRelay component when relaying mail

Tags: delphi, ssl, smtp, indy, smtps

I'd like to know if there is a way to use my server certificates when relaying mail using the `TIdSMTPRelay` component in `indy`. This is how the mail relaying part in my code looks like :

```
procedure TMyForm.SMTPServerMsgReceive(ASender: TIdSMTPServerContext; AMsg : TStream; 
  var LAction: TIdDataReply);      
begin
  //The AMsg (TStream) is being transformed to MsgDecode (TIdMessage) and 
  // all relay recipients to RelayRecipients (TIdEMailAddressList) using     
  // [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499524/using-indy-smtpserver]

  // SSLRelayHandler is a TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSsl indy component and SMTPRelay is 
  // a TIdSMTPRelay indy component 
  SMTPRelay.DNSServer := myDNSServer;
  SSLRelayHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23; 
  SSLRelayHandler.SSLOptions.KeyFile := myMailServerKey;
  SSLRelayHandler.SSLOptions.CertFile := myMailServerCert;
  SSLRelayHandler.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := myMailServerRootCert;
  SMTPRelay.IOHandler := SSLRelayHandler;
  SMTPRelay.SSLOptions.SSLSupport := SupportSSL;
  try
    SMTPRelay.Send(MsgDecode, RelayRecipients); 
  except on e : Exception do 
  end;
end;
```

Sometimes the mail is never sent and sometimes it's being sent but goes to the spam section (yahoo) although I'm issuing a `STARTTLS` command thanks to the attached `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` to my `TIdSMTPRelay`. Can I connect to another mail server's `SMTPS` port `465` or the `TIdSMTPRelay` component can only send to port `25` ? For more details this is how the communication with yahoo looks like :

```
Stat Connected.
Recv 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:15: 220 mta1418.mail.gq1.yahoo.com ESMTP ready<EOL>
Sent 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:15: EHLO mail.mydomain.com<EOL>
Recv 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:15: 250-mta1418.mail.gq1.yahoo.com<EOL>250-PIPELINING<EOL>250-SIZE      41943040<EOL>250-8BITMIME<EOL>250 STARTTLS<EOL>
Sent 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:15: STARTTLS<EOL>
Recv 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:15: 220 Start TLS<EOL>
Sent 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:16: EHLO mail.mydomain.com<EOL>
Recv 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:16: 250-mta1418.mail.gq1.yahoo.com<EOL>250-PIPELINING<EOL>250-SIZE 41943040<EOL>250 8BITMIME<EOL>
Sent 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:16: MAIL FROM:<user229@mail.mydomain.com><EOL>
Recv 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:16: 250 sender <user229@mail.mydomain.com> ok<EOL>
Sent 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:16: RCPT TO:<test_user_mail@yahoo.com><EOL>
Recv 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:16: 250 recipient <test_user_mail@yahoo.com> ok<EOL>
Sent 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:16: DATA<EOL>
Recv 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:17: 354 go ahead<EOL>
Sent 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:17: From: "user229@mail.mydomain.com" <user229@mail.mydomain.com>   <EOL>Subject: =?UTF-8?B?0JfQsNCz0LvQsNCy0LjQtTIy?=<EOL>To: test_user_mail@yahoo.com<EOL>Date: Thu, 23     Oct 2014 15:32:17 +0300<EOL>
Sent 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:17: <EOL>
Sent 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:17: body of the mail here<EOL>
Sent 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:17: <EOL>
Sent 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:17: .<EOL>
Recv 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:18: 250 ok dirdel<EOL>
Sent 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:18: QUIT<EOL>
Recv 23.10.2014 ?. 15:32:18: 221 mta1418.mail.gq1.yahoo.com<EOL>
Stat Disconnected.
```

Answer (score 2):

`TIdSMTPRelay` can use other ports.  You should leave the `Port` property set to its default (25) so that it can toggle between 25 and 465 based on how it manages its SSL/TLS connections internally.

The `SSLOptions` property controls how `TIdSMTPRelay` manages its SSL/TLS connections. `SSLOptions.SSLSupport` can be set to `NoSSL`, `SupportSSL`, or `RequireSSL`, and `SSLOptions.TryImplicitTLS` can be set to either True or False.  See the implementation in `TIdSMTPRelay.Connect()`.

When `SSLOptions.TryImplicitTLS` is true (port 465), `Send()` will attempt to use `UseTLS=utImplicitTLS` when connecting.  Meaning that a SSL/TLS handshake will be initiated as soon as the socket is connected.

If that fails, or if `SSLOptions.TryImplicitTLS` is false (ports 25 and 587), `Send()` will use `UseTLS=utNoTLSSupport`, `UseTLS=utUseExplicitTLS`, or `UseTLS= utUseRequireTLS` depending on the value of `SSLOptions.SSLSupport`:

`NoSSL`: the SMTP session will be unencrypted.

`SupportSSL`: the SMTP session will be initiated unencrypted, then `STARTTLS` will be sent to the SMTP server only if supported, otherwise the SMTP session will continue unencrypted.  If the SSL/TLS handshake fails, an exception will be raised.

`RequireSSL`: the SMTP session will be initiated unencrypted, then `STARTTLS` will be sent to the SMTP server if supported, otherwise the SMTP session will be closed with an exception raised.  If the SSL/TLS handshake fails, an exception will be raised.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanation - what I still don't understand is how to attach (if it's possible) the server certificates to the ``TIdSMTPRelay`` - is my way correct or not. And is there a way to test if the other mail server (for example yahoo) can verify my ssl certificates - when I tried the ``SMTPRelay.SSLOptions.TryImplicitTLS := True;`` it returned me ``Connection timed out`` error for both yahoo and gmail - aren't they suppose to support ``SMTPS`` ?